# How can i make my verilog shifter more general?

Tags: verilog

Here i have a shifter but as of rite now it only works for up to 3 bits. I've been looking and i can't find out how to make it work for up to 8 bits.

```
module shifter(a,b,out);
input [7:0] a, b;
output [7:0] out;
wire [7:0] out1, out2, out3;

mux_8b_2to1 first(a[7:0], {a[3:0],a[7:4]}, b[2], out1);
mux_8b_2to1 second(out1[7:0], {out1[5:0],out1[7:6]}, b[1], out2);
mux_8b_2to1 third(out2[7:0], {out2[6:0],out2[7]}, b[0], out);
endmodule
```

Answer (score 5):

What you have is a [Barrel Shifter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter). Two ways to make it more generic are make it a functional model (still synthesis-able) or structural model with a generate block. Both approaches follow IEEE Std 1364-2001 (aka Verilog-2001).

The functional generic approach for a barrel shifter only needs a down-shifter. The general function is `out = {in,in} >> (WIDTH-shift)` where leftover bits can be ignored. To protect for double-roll (i.e. shift > WIDTH ), use the mod operator on the shift (`WIDTH-(shift%WIDTH)`).

```
module barrel_shifter_functional #( parameter CTRL=3, parameter WIDTH=CTRL**2 )
 ( input wire [WIDTH-1:0] in,
   input wire [ CTRL-1:0] shift,
  output wire [WIDTH-1:0] out );
assign out = {2{in}} >> (WIDTH-(shift%WIDTH));
endmodule
```

The structural generic approach for a barrel shifter needs a generate block. The for loop in the generate block will unravel at compile time, not run time like a for loop like in an always block. To keep it generic also have have the 2-to-1 mux have a parametrized width. *FYI, you can use the generate block with functional code too, for example comment out the `mux_2to1` instantiation and uncomment the assign statement below it.* Learn more about the generate block by reading [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 27. Generate constructs.

```
module barrel_shifter_structeral #( parameter CTRL=3, parameter WIDTH=CTRL**2 )
 ( input wire [WIDTH-1:0] in,
   input wire [ CTRL-1:0] shift,
  output wire [WIDTH-1:0] out );
wire [WIDTH-1:0] tmp [CTRL:0];
assign tmp[CTRL] = in;
assign out = tmp[0];
genvar i;
generate
  for (i = 0; i < CTRL; i = i + 1) begin : mux
    mux_2to1 #(.WIDTH(WIDTH)) g(
      .in0(tmp[i+1]),
      .in1({tmp[i+1][WIDTH-(2**i)-1:0],tmp[i+1][WIDTH-1:WIDTH-(2**i)]}),
      .sel(shift[i]),
      .out(tmp[i]) );
    // assign tmp[i] = shift[i] ? {tmp[i+1][WIDTH-(2**i)-1:0],tmp[i+1][WIDTH-1:WIDTH-(2**i)]} : tmp[i+1];
  end : mux
endgenerate
endmodule

module mux_2to1 #( parameter WIDTH=8 )
 ( input wire [WIDTH-1:0] in0, in1,
   input wire             sel,
  output wire [WIDTH-1:0] out );
assign out = sel ? in1 : in0;
endmodule
```

Both examples are functionally equivalent and synthesize provided `CTRL` is less than or equal to the ceiling of log2(`WIDTH`). Synthesis will likely give different results. The generate method will exclusively use 2-to-1 muxes while the pure functional method will depend on the quality of the optimizer.

Working example @ http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/500

Answer (score 0):

I've used the >> and << operators to generate a synthetizable design using ISEWebPack, as this:

```
module shifter(
    input wire [7:0] a,
    input wire [7:0] b,
    input wire leftright,  // 0=shift right, 1=shift left
    output reg [7:0] out
    );

    always @* begin
      if (leftright==0)
         out = a>>b;
      else
         out = a<<b;
    end
endmodule
```

This way, the symthesis tool will know that you want to implement a shifter and can use its own macros to best synthetize it:

```
Synthesizing Unit <shifter>.
    Related source file is "shifter.v".
    Found 8-bit shifter logical right for signal <out$shift0002> created at line 30.
    Found 8-bit shifter logical left for signal <out$shift0003> created at line 32.
```