# How do I implement a parameterized barrel shifter (rotator)?

Tags: system-verilog

I just implemented a rotator that rotates an 8 bits from 0 to 7 bits using an 8:1 muxes.

Now, I need to implement a rotator that has an input of 64 bits and an amount shifted. 
I could just make a 64:1 bit mux but that's too much work and can't be right.

How do I solve this problem? (preferable a parameterized version that works for both the 8 and 64 bit version)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i make my verilog shifter more general?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357390/how-can-i-make-my-verilog-shifter-more-general)

Comment: It seems to me you're thinking too low level. You're trying to do structural design, when you could be doing functional design and let your synthesis tool do the heavy lifting.

Comment: It would be good if you included what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

A rotator can be as straight forward as this:

```
parameter W = 64;
logic [W-1:0] data_in;
logic [W-1:0] data_out;

logic [$clog2(W)-1:0] shift;

always_comb begin
  data_out = {data_in, data_in} >> shift;
end
```

If you need to remove issue surrounding assignment width mismatch you can add do:

```
logic [W-1:0] temp;
always_comb begin
  {temp, data_out} = {data_in, data_in} >> shift;
end
```