# Permuation in SystemVerilog using genvar

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado

I am working on a piece of code for permutation. I could not find a nice of assigning signals indexed with genvar and an input.

I have input `i` with array of 4, and output `o` again with same size. And I have a permutation index. Depending on the permutation index, I want to assign outputs to inputs such as:

```
perm_index 0 | o[0] <- i[0] | o[1] <- i[1] | o[2] <- i[2] | o[3] <- i[3]
perm_index 1 | o[0] <- i[1] | o[1] <- i[0] | o[2] <- i[3] | o[3] <- i[2]
perm_index 2 | o[0] <- i[2] | o[1] <- i[3] | o[2] <- i[0] | o[3] <- i[1]
perm_index 3 | o[0] <- i[3] | o[1] <- i[2] | o[2] <- i[1] | o[3] <- i[0]
```

This is the permutation that I want to code, and I want to use genvar for this. In my coding with `genvar g` and `input [1:0] perm_index`, this line `o[g].addr <= i[g^perm_index].addr;` causes an error "perm_index is not a constant".

Does anyone knows a better way to write this code?

---

First I coded my permutation using a `generate` block, such as:

```
genvar g;
generate
for (g=0; g<4; g++)
  always_comb
    o[g].addr <= i[g^perm_index].addr;
endgenerate
```

However, Vivado does not accept this code, throwing out an error "perm_index is not a constant".

I could solve it by writing the code as shown below.

```
genvar g;
generate
for (g=0; g<4; g++)
  always_comb
    case (g[1:0])
      (2'd0^perm_index) : o[g].addr <= i[0].addr;
      (2'd1^perm_index) : o[g].addr <= i[1].addr;
      (2'd2^perm_index) : o[g].addr <= i[2].addr;
      (2'd3^perm_index) : o[g].addr <= i[3].addr;
    endcase
endgenerate
```

Although this is a solution, I am not happy with this coding style. Does anyone knows a better way to write this code?

Comment: I believe that there is a vivado bug with the first example, however both examples are very different and would produce different results if they work. The question is: what do you really expect? and what is `i`?

Comment: @Serge `i` and `o` stands for for `inputs` and `outputs`. I have four inputs `i[0]`, `i[1]`, `i[2]` and `i[3]`. And for outputs the same way. And this is the assignment, that I want to have:


if perm_index 0 then `o[0] <- i[0]   o[1] <- i[1]   o[2] <- i[2]  o[3] <- i[3]`,
if perm_index 1 then `o[0] <- i[1]   o[1] <- i[0]   o[2] <- i[3]  o[3] <- i[2]`,
if perm_index 2 then `o[0] <- i[2]   o[1] <- i[3]   o[2] <- i[0]  o[3] <- i[1]`,
if perm_index 3 then `o[0] <- i[3]   o[1] <- i[2]   o[2] <- i[1]  o[3] <- i[0]`.

Comment: @Mikef No, I use `^` for XOR, not for power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks lie you are trying to implement some weird bit swapping. I kind of guess what it is but straight forward implementation for this example is much easier than an attempt to create a *clever* algorithm for it.

In any case, you do not need any generate statement at all. It is a special construct and it is supposed to be used for configuration purposes or algorithmic instantiation of multiple design elements. You do not have either.

So, I tried to follow your picture and created a possible implementation with a 'case' statement as the following:

```
module perm(input logic[1:0] perm_index, input logic[3:0]i, output logic [3:0] o);  

  always_comb begin
    case(perm_index)
      0: o = i;
      1: o = {i[1], i[0], i[3], i[2]};
      2: o = {i[2], i[3], i[0], i[1]};
      3: o = {i[3], i[2], i[1], i[0]};
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

I do not think that you can get it easier than that, unless you have much bigger vectors.

And here is a simple test bench

```
module top;
  logic [3:0] perm_index;
  logic [3:0] i, o;
  
  perm perm(perm_index, i, o);
  
  initial begin
    $monitor("%0t> %0d: %b --> %b", $time, perm_index, i, o);
    i = 4'b1100;
    
    for (int pi = 0; pi < 7; pi++) begin
      perm_index = pi;
      #2;
    end
    
    #2 $finish;
  end
  
endmodule
```

As it turned out, OP used System Verilog interfaces. Below is an example with interfaces.

First is  a straight forward one with concats:

```
module perm(input logic[1:0] perm_index, I i[4], I o[4]);  
  always_comb begin
    case(perm_index)
      0: {o[0].addr, o[1].addr, o[2].addr, o[3].addr} = 
         {i[0].addr, i[1].addr, i[2].addr, i[3].addr};
      1: {o[0].addr, o[1].addr, o[2].addr, o[3].addr}  = 
         {i[1].addr, i[0].addr, i[3].addr, i[2].addr};
      2: {o[0].addr, o[1].addr, o[2].addr, o[3].addr}  = 
         {i[2].addr, i[3].addr, i[0].addr, i[1].addr};
      3: {o[0].addr, o[1].addr, o[2].addr, o[3].addr}  = 
         {i[3].addr, i[2].addr, i[1].addr, i[0].addr};
    endcase
  end
  
endmodule
```

Here is one with genblocks:

```
module perm(input logic[1:0] perm_index, I i[4], I o[4]);  
  parameter int perm_i[4][4] = '{
    '{0, 1, 2, 3},
    '{1, 0, 3, 2},
    '{2, 3, 0, 1},
    '{3, 2, 1, 0}};
              
  for (genvar v = 0; v < 4; v++) begin
    always_comb
      case (perm_index)
        0: o[v].addr = i[perm_i[0][v]].addr;
        1: o[v].addr = i[perm_i[1][v]].addr;
        2: o[v].addr = i[perm_i[2][v]].addr;
        3: o[v].addr = i[perm_i[3][v]].addr;
      endcase
  end
endmodule
```

And an updated testbench

```
interface I;
  logic[3:0] addr;
endinterface

module top;
  I i[4]();
  I o[4]();  
  logic [3:0] perm_index;
  perm perm(perm_index, i, o);
    
  initial begin
    $monitor("%2t> [%0d], i(%0d,%0d,%0d,%0d) --> o(%0d,%0d,%0d,%0d)", 
             $time, perm_index,
             i[0].addr, i[1].addr, i[2].addr, i[3].addr,
             o[0].addr, o[1].addr, o[2].addr, o[3].addr);
                
    {i[0].addr, i[1].addr, i[2].addr, i[3].addr} = {4'd1, 4'd2, 4'd3, 4'd4};
    
    for (int pi = 0; pi < 7; pi++) begin
      perm_index = pi;
      #2;
    end
       #2 $finish;
       
  end
  
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for testing the code already. Indeed, writing the code as you did looks nice and clean. But, not that preferable for me. First, you concatenated {`i[0], i[1], ...`}. But, the `i` and `o` are interfaces for me. AFAIK, I cannot concatenate interfaces. So, I need a separate line for every signal of the interface. Another problem is the sizes. To make the question easy, I asked it with an array size of 4; however, the array sizes can be 16 or 64 in different modules. Copy-pasting same line 64 times is not interesting anymore, that is why I am looking for using genvar.

Comment: ok, you have not mentioned interfaces before. Please provide a reproducible code sample with full info.

Comment: I added a couple of examples with SV interfaces.

Comment: Thanks Serge. These are very nice approaches. 2D array for indexes is not something I would not consider. I learnt nice tricks from you. Thanks. However, I have to conclude that, there is not clean way of coding this permutation, I mean in several lines. Depending on the permutation index length, and the number of interface signals, the code might grow. In the meantime, I switched to Verilator and checked its error messages too, and no help from there either. So, in the end, I am convinced to use the version with the `case()`, your concatenation is also very neat, maybe I can switch to that.

Comment: Dealing with generated constructs, like arrayed instances of interfaces (or modules) has its limits in verilog. You might be able to switch to arrays of variables instead (i.e., instead of array of interface, use a single interface with array of addr). It will allow you to use dynamic constructs and provide more flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

Permutation is possible with gen var. What you aree trying to achieve is actually a rotation. You can obtain it with modulo operation.

It is possibile provided that `perm_index` is a constant value, eg: parameter.

It is good practice to have a constant width value for array size. I show a full example:

```
module top;

parameter logic[1:0] PERM_INDEX=0;
parameter ARRAY_W= 4;

typedef struct{
  int addr;
} my_t;

my_t i[ARRAY_W]; 
my_t o[ARRAY_W];


initial begin;
  for(int j=0; j<ARRAY_W; j++) begin
    i[j].addr = j+ 10;
    $display("i[%d].addr = %d", j, i[j].addr);
  end
  #10;
  for(int j=0; j<ARRAY_W; j++) begin
    $display("o[%d].addr = %d", j, o[j].addr);
  end
end

genvar g;
generate
for (g=0; g<ARRAY_W; g++)
    assign o[g].addr = i[(g+PERM_INDEX)%ARRAY_W].addr;
endgenerate

endmodule
```

------------------ EDIT ------------

To have `perm_index` changing over the time, the best approach is to use a barrel shifter.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter

Already answered here:

[How can i make my verilog shifter more general?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357390/how-can-i-make-my-verilog-shifter-more-general)

Comment: But, the OP requires perm_index to be a variable which changes over time, not a constant.  That is the point of the question.

Comment: @toolic Indeed `perm_index` varies over time. That is the limitation.

Comment: You are looking for an implementation of the `barrel shifter`, I edited the answer

Comment: No (Apparently, I have to reply with something longer than just `No`)